# MacOS change build configuration using bash and msbuild

Tags: bash, msbuild

I would like to build the Release configuration with a bash script.
My problem is that it builds the Debug configuration by default.

How can I pass the configuration to a bash command line ?

For the moment I use this :

```
find "MyUITestPATH" -regex '.*UITest.*\.csproj' -exec msbuild {} \;
```

and it build in DEBUG configuration. I need to build my UITest in Release configuration.

Answer (score 2):

When you invoke msbuild.exe you can pass in command line parameters.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2017

The command line param you want to set is a property (i.e. `-property`, or `-p` for short). 
In your case you will specify:

```
-p:Configuration=Release
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it :

```
find "MyUITestPATH" -regex '.*UITest.*\.csproj' -exec msbuild {} -p:Configuration=Release \;
```